# What's the effect of export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...?

Tags: cmake

When google-ing `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, you will often find the suggestion to cure the problem that CMake doesn't find this or that package by setting an environment variable:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/package
```

I've convinced myself that setting this environment variable has the effect of *appending* `/path/to/package` to the list of paths specified in the CMake call using

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/package1;..." .
```

(I've tried this on macOS Catalina and Ubuntu 18.04 using CMake 3.15.5 and 3.16.0, respectively.)

The documentation doesn't mention any of this. In fact, it simply states:

> By default this [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`] is empty. It is intended to be set by the project.

(see [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html)). There's no mention of the effect of setting the environment variable.

This raises two questions:

- Is this effect of setting the environment variable intended? Where is it documented? Is this the canonical way of adding prefix paths to *all* projects build in the environment?
- As the documentation says, "It [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`] is intended to be set by the project". Is there any reason why there *shouldn't* be a way to set a default `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of setting it as an environment variable is, by default, no effect. CMake defines it's own variables (those set with the set() command, or the -D command line argument) in a file called CMakeCache.txt in the root of your CMake project. Those are the variables which will affect your cmake script.

In order to access and environment variable in CMake, you need to specify the [ENV Syntax](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html)

```
$ENV{VAR}
```

Hence, even if you set a CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable, it will have no effect unless you explicitly use it in you CMakeLists.txt.

(Edit: I have only verified this behavior on Windows 10 with CMake 3.16.3)

Comment: "The effect of setting it as an environment variable is, by default, no effect." Do you have a reference for this? As I mentioned in the question, I have verified that under Linux and macOS, the value of  the environment variable is appended to the list set using the `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` directive.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-language.7.html#cmake-language-environment-variables. The behavior you are observing seems to be os dependant, as I was unable to reproduce it on Windows

Comment: Great, thanks! - So how do you tell CMake to use some path as prefix path for _all_ projects?

Comment: The only way I see of doing this, as of now, is to generate projects with a custum initial cache. In order to accomplish this, you run the generation command with the -C option leading to an initial cache file. For example, imagine you had the file **default-cache.cmake** with content `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "Path/to/stuff" CACHE PATH "Initial CMake cache" FORCE)` You could would invoke the cmake generation command like this `cmake /path/to/project -C "/path/to/some-cache.cmake"` To make things easier for yourself, define the cache-file path as a environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable works in finding things with function `find_file`, `find_path`, etc.

Just because by default these functions use the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable as a path hint as well as the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable set via `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=xx` or set function.